# Normalisation or Standardisation for detecting outlier?

Tags: statistics, normalization

When to use min max scaling that is normalisation and when to use standardisation that is using z score for data pre-processing ?

I know that normalisation brings down the range of feature to 0 to 1, and z score bring downs to -3 to 3, but am unsure when to use one of the two technique for detecting the outliers in data?

Answer (score 1):

Let us briefly agree on the terms:

- The [z-score](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_score) tells us how many standard deviations a given element of a sample is away from the mean.
- The [min-max scaling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_scaling) is the method of  rescaling a range of measurements the interval [0, 1].

By those definitions, z-score usually spans an interval much larger than [-3,3] if your data follows a long-tailed distribution. On the other hand, a plain **normalization does indeed limit the range of the possible outcomes, but will not help you help you to find outliers**, since it just bounds the data.

What you need for outlier dedetction are thresholds above or below which you consider a data point to be an outlier. Many programming languages offer [Violin plots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Violin_plot) or [Box plots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box_plot) which nicely show your data distribution. The methods behind plots implement a common choice of thresholds:

> Box and whisker [of the box plot] plots quartiles, and the band inside the box is always the second quartile (the median). But the ends of the whiskers can represent several possible alternative values, among them:
>
> - the minimum and maximum of all of the data [...]
> - one standard deviation above and below the mean of the data
> - the 9th percentile and the 91st percentile
> - the 2nd percentile and the 98th percentile.

All data points outside the whiskers of the box plots are plotted as points and considered outliers.